# How do I reverse a Int Array?

Tags: java, arrays, int, reverse

Complete the reverseValues method which is passed an array of ints(values) as a parameter. The method returns the ints(values) with the order of the numbers reversed.

For example, if the input array is
{3, 7, 2, 4}

the method returns {4,2,7,3}

An example:
reverseValues({3, 7, 2, 4}) should return {4,2,7,3}

I can't find any help that shows how to do this without seeing the array before hand.

Comment: Just think of the problem as `array.length/2` number swaps...

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i =0; i < array.length/2; i++){
   int temp = array[i];
   array[i] = array[array.length-1 - i];
   array[array.length-1 - i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: I bet you could do it in place.

Comment: do you mean the temp variable? this swap should be in place minus the single variable overhead.

Comment: I misread the code, and yes you are right, the temp variable is just fine. +1

Comment: You can do it without the variable using XOR ;)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried looking at trying to convert the array to a list, and then call:

```
 public ArrayList<String> reverse(ArrayList<String> list) {
     ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(list.size());

    for(int i=list.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
       result.add(list.get(i));
    }    

    return result;
}
```

Something like this should work. Might not be the fastest, but it will reverse the list.

Comment: Where are you finding this method?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've been using Groovy for too long! I'll update my post.

Comment: I tend to think this approach is a bit heavy for such a simple task.  But the way closest to your initial approach would be it would be Arrays#asList and Collections#reverse.